# Running aspnetcore 2.2 app on Web App for Containers on windows

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

I'm want to run aspnetcore 2.2 web app in azure, using windows docker containers,
but container fails starting with following message

> ERROR - Site: test-container-bonee - Image pull reported error. Image:
> containersbonee.azurecr.io/soarcdockertest:1.0. failed to register
> layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: remove
> \?\C:\DockerData\windowsfilter\1889bb89045f68ca9052065efa6ea07b24da7e725d2adb2aacc8294318fecb6c\UtilityVM\Files\Windows\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-UtilityVM-Core-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.14393.0.cat:
> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
> process.
>
> 25/01/2019 10:31:06.022 INFO - Site: test-container-bonee -
> Image: containersbonee.azurecr.io/soarcdockertest:1.0 Custom Registry:
> https://containersbonee.azurecr.io
>
> 25/01/2019 10:31:06.025 INFO - Site: test-container-bonee - Purging
> after container failed to start
>
> 25/01/2019 10:31:06.025 ERROR - Site:
> test-container-bonee - Pull image completed but it was not found
> locally. Image: containersbonee.azurecr.io/soarcdockertest:1.0.
> Errors: failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1:
> output: remove
> \?\C:\DockerData\windowsfilter\1889bb89045f68ca9052065efa6ea07b24da7e725d2adb2aacc8294318fecb6c\UtilityVM\Files\Windows\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-UtilityVM-Core-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.14393.0.cat:
> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
> process.

Here is my dockerfiler

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-sac2016 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk-nanoserver-sac2016 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Soarc.DockerTest/Soarc.DockerTest.csproj", "Soarc.DockerTest/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Soarc.DockerTest/Soarc.DockerTest.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Soarc.DockerTest"
RUN dotnet build "Soarc.DockerTest.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Soarc.DockerTest.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Soarc.DockerTest.dll"]
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Switch to Linux like everyone else and enjoy the rest of your day? Do you have Windows dependencies?

Comment: Currently there is 50 percent discount on windows, and i want to try it on windows